# undefined in variable using react componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have no clue why this.role is undefined in render.

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.role = window.localStorage.getItem('role')
    console.log('role', this.role) //return admin
  }

  render(){
    console.log('role', this.role) //return undefined
    return(
      <div>
        Component
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I checked the localStorage of my app and it has value.

Answer (score 3):

It's returning undefined because you're setting `this.role` **after** the component is mount (`componentDidMount`). So the first render doesn't have `this.role`.

After `componentDidMount` is run you're not changing the state and the render is not running again (and therefore not getting the new info).

Try with `componentWillMount` instead, it should probably work.

Here's the [React Lifecycle documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Edit: Added code.

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.role = window.localStorage.getItem('role')
    console.log('role', this.role) // return admin
  }

  render(){
    console.log('role', this.role) // now returning admin because this.role is set before the 1st render
    return(
      <div>
        Component
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As other users have pointed out, you can also use setState instead and it would also work (In that case, when the state changes the render is run again and your role is displayed accordingly).

Comment: with `componentWillMount` it will work for sure. With an example of the code it should be the most accurate answer.

Comment: Yeah,this is related to life cycle of react

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas Thank you. Will add an example to my answer in order to have it more useful!

Answer (score 3):

what happens is that at the initial render, render() method is called (before componentDidMount() is called), so it shows 'undefined'.
changing the value of 'this.role' won't re-render the page.

You will have to use state for this.
Below code should work I believe.

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    role : undefined
    }
} 

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({role: window.localStorage.getItem('role')})
    console.log('role', this.role) //return admin
  }

  render(){
    console.log('role', this.state.role) //return undefined
    return(
      <div>
        Component
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You see `undefined` in the view because by the time the component has rendered there was nothing in `role` because `componentDidMount` is called after the initial render. Moreover, the component doesn't rerender after you have set `role` value from `localStorage` because it is not on the state. If you place `role` on the state and do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ role: window.localStorage.getItem('role')});
}

render(){
  console.log('role', this.state.role)
  return(
      <div>
        Component
      </div>
    )
}
```

then you will be able to see value of `role` in the view, but it will cause extra rerender of the component since you will change its `state`, according to react docs about `componentDidMount`:

> Calling setState() in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but
>   it will happen before the browser updates the screen.

You can read more about `componentDidMount` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

---

Update:

In your case you don't have to put `role` on the state, but then you can fetch its value from the `constructor`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.role = window.localStorage.getItem('role');
}
```

and it will be available in the view.